# Azure Role assign to group in TF

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a new group and assign owner role to it via terraform but i'm facing issue to assignment .

Below is the code

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {
}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}




resource "azuread_group" "group" {
  display_name  = "azure-group"
  security_enabled = False
}


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role-assign" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = "Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.group.object_id
}
```

When is run the plan is see this error

````
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│ 
│   on main.tf line 18, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role-assign":
│   18:   principal_id         = data.azuread_group.group.object_id
│ 
│ A data resource "azuread_group" "group" has not been declared in the root module.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using resource, not data source. So instead of

```
principal_id         = data.azuread_group.group.object_id
```

it should be

```
principal_id         = azuread_group.group.object_id
```